# how to fix the little flick in Bootstrap 3 affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement Affix navigation bar with bootstrap3, According to this example:http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp, When i scroll down slowly there's a little flick.I got think a lot, But i couldn't find any solution to fix that. This video shows exactly what i mean: http://sendvid.com/rf8t26hw .

How can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"flick" as you called is caused by element going from static to fixed position (element with affix class/functionality behaviour). That is causing DOM to move up as the affix element is not occupying the same height in the dom tree.

Solution for that is to have a wrapper around "affixed" element with minimum height declared (and matching the affixed element) so once the affix goes to position:fixed, wrapper would take his place in dom tree and hence eliminate the "bug".

Example code [here](http://codeply.com/go/kcy7eYSQvb)